# Digital Western Hdrive freezing - Bad hard drive

Tags: crash, crash-reports, hard-drive

A week ago my computer start freezing every couple of seconds to 30sec-2minutes.
So i open my proccess explorer to monitor it to see if i get some CPU spikes and if so, which application is causing it.. after some freezes i noticed non of my programs/services is causing the freezes.
so i tried to check if any of my fans aren't working.. but all fans are working great.
adventually i ran the chkdsk scan (in the way i had tons of crashes/ startup problems/ i even couldnt run the windows installation disk due to a memory diagnostic problems.. I HAD Really lots of lots of problems)

adventually i found the problem, it's appear my DW hard drive is faulty and here the hard drive results:
http://pastie.org/2949300

now i'm searching the web for a tool that could fix all it's problems because i really need the drive to work.

Windows 7 ultimate 64bit.
intel e6320
4gb ddr2
ati hd5450.

Please help me if you can guide me what can i do to fix it.. (my os is on it)

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, try to get a backup of your harddrive / your data**. All actions you´re performing right now can lead to a data loss.

I don´t know if there are a web tool for fixing these problems - normally, a extended chkdsk (/r /p) should´ve fix the problems. Your log shows insufficient space on the partition. Can you move some files on another disk and try to run chkdsk again?

Comment: i did the /r /p because that at the log it tried to fix the currupt files..

I have on that drive: 60.7gb used space out of 172gb free space..

so theres enough drive space..

Comment: @OTTA: agreed! Backup your data, install Windows on a new HD and try to move your data back. S.M.A.R.T. Values of the old HD would be interesting - you can use the  [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) to read them out. Also, there are diagnostic tools on this Boot CD from the HD Manufacturer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a new hard drive, install windows on that and see what you can read of the old disk. You're getting read and write errors in chkdsk, crashes etc, the disk is on the way out.